# 'dict' object has no attribute 'save' POST doesn't work

Tags: python, django, rest, post, django-rest-framework

I'm building a REST web service, the GET method seems to be working all right
but when it comes to POST error message always shows up:
    **'dict' object has no attribute 'save'**

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Users(models.Model):
    Fullname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Username = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Password = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    Email = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    Type = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    TwitterName = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    FacebookName = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    CreationDate = models.DateTimeField()
```

**serializer.py**

```
    class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ('Fullname', 'Username', 'Email', 'Password', 'Type', 'TwitterName', 'FacebookName')
```

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def users_list(request, format=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        users = Users.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UserSerializer(request.DATA, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I'm using PyCharm and Django 1.7

Comment: Is your `UserSerializer` literally indented that way?  Class `Meta` is supposed to be a nest inner-class of `UserSerializer`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the POST data then you should pass the data to `data` keyword argument:

```
serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.DATA, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            ...
```

Also I would suggest you to use [Class based views with Mixins](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views#using-mixins) as that will make your code much cleaner and shorter:

```
from rest_framework import generics, mixins

class UserList(mixins.ListModelMixin,
               mixins.CreateModelMixin,
               generics.GenericAPIView):

    queryset = Users.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I did that at first but then again I get another error: **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'** so I removed data=request.DATA and wrote request.DATA only

Comment: I tried using the class based views I still get the same error: **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'** I'm not even sure what the problem is.

Comment: @Sara I am not sure how you're getting that error. Try to do some debugging by logging the value of serializer after and before the `.is_valid()` call.

Comment: @Sara By the way are you sure this is the view causing the issue and have you restarted the server after making the changes?

Comment: I tried returning the value of the serializer and it has data:

Comment: I tried the following: if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.data) the serializer has data but for some reason when it comes to serializer.save() I get the same error